# Liferay - React portlet: MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, liferay-7

I am building a npm-react portlet in liferay 7 and i am trying to use https://react-table.js.org for rendering the table data. When i try to access the portlet in brower i get the erro in the screen shot below:

Error:
[image]

MyJS file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Clock from './components/Clock'
import ReactTable from "react-table";
import 'react-table/react-table.css'

function Mytable() {
    const data = [{
        name: 'Tanner Linsley',
        age: 26,
        friend: {
            name: 'Jason Maurer',
            age: 23,
        }
    }];

    const columns = [{
        Header: 'Name',
        accessor: 'name' // String-based value accessors!
    }, {
        Header: 'Age',
        accessor: 'age',
        Cell: props => <span className='number'>{props.value}</span> // Custom cell components!
    }, {
        id: 'friendName', // Required because our accessor is not a string
        Header: 'Friend Name',
        accessor: d => d.friend.name // Custom value accessors!
    }, {
        Header: props => <span>Friend Age</span>, // Custom header components!
        accessor: 'friend.age'
    }];

    return (<ReactTable
        data={data}
        columns={columns}
    />);
}

export default function (elementId) {
    console.log("default");
    ReactDOM.render(<Mytable/>, document.getElementById(elementId));
}
```